# Is there a way to make a custom implementation of Nashorn JSObject work with Object.keys()?

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I recently asked this question [How can I pass a proper method reference in so Nashorn can execute it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222083/how-can-i-pass-a-proper-method-reference-in-so-nashorn-can-execute-it) and got an answer that helped me get much further along with my project, but I discovered a limitation around providing a custom JSObject implementation that I don't know how to resolve.

Given this simple working JSObject that can handle most of the methods JS would invoke on it such as map:

```
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class scratch_6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        // The following JSObject wraps this list
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("hello");
        l.add("world");
        l.add(true);
        l.add(1);

        JSObject jsObj = new AbstractJSObject() {
            @Override
            public Object getMember(String name) {
                if (name.equals("map")) {
                    // return a functional interface object - nashorn will treat it like
                    // script function!
                    final Function<JSObject, Object> jsObjectObjectFunction = callback -> {
                        List<Object> res = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Object obj : l) {
                            // call callback on each object and add the result to new list
                            res.add(callback.call(null, obj));
                        }

                        // return fresh list as result of map (or this could be another wrapper)
                        return res;
                    };
                    return jsObjectObjectFunction;
                } else {
                    // unknown property
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };

        e.put("obj", jsObj);
        // map each String to it's uppercase and print result of map
        e.eval("print(obj.map(function(x) '\"'+x.toString()+'\"'))");

        //PROBLEM
        //e.eval("print(Object.keys(obj))");
    }
}
```

If you uncomment the last line where Object.keys(obj) is called, it will fail with the error `... is not an Object`.

This appears to be because Object.keys() [ NativeObject.java:376 ] only checks whether the object is an instance of ScriptObject or of ScriptObjectMirror.  If it is neither of those things, it throws the notAnObject error. :(

Comment: I found https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154720 in the JDK JIRA, which says that Object.keys() is not expected to work for Java objects, but note the difference in this case is that my class is implementing JSObject which means to me that it should be compatible.

Comment: I also found https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015830 which touches on a similar area, and implemented a fix, but the fix did not cover JSObject interface itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, user implemented JSObject objects should be exactly equivalent to script objects. But, user implemented JSObjects are *almost* script objects - but not quite. This is documented here -> https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes

Object.keys is one such case where it breaks. However, if you just want for..in javascript iteration support for your objects, you can implement JSObject.keySet in your class.

Example code:

```
import javax.script.*;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        // This JSObject wraps the following Properties object
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        JSObject jsObj = new AbstractJSObject() {
            @Override
            public Set<String> keySet() {
                return props.stringPropertyNames();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getMember(String name) {
                return props.getProperty(name);
            }
        };

        e.put("obj", jsObj);
        e.eval("for (i in obj) print(i, ' = ', obj[i])");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am calling into third party code which is using Object.keys() so I don't have the option to swap it out for something else.  Would it be worth putting a RFE in for jdk9 to have Object.keys test for JSObject instead of just ScriptObjectMirror?

Comment: Yes, please do file a bug/rfe against openjdk.

Comment: RFE filed, internal review ID : 9049306

Comment: Thanks for filing the rfe!